# After waking up, mouse clicks don't work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mouse

If i am away from my computer for an amount of time my screen turns off. I then shake the mouse to wake it back up, however clicks don't work. The mouse moves around, and the keyboard works.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you saying you have to reboot your PC for the clicks to work or is it just a delay before they work again? Is it wired mouse, wireless? Any additional software relating to it? USB or PS2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a new mouse. Or borrow one from a friend Try both PS2 and USB.